# _explain query please explain why clauses look like this

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm migrating ES 2.x to ES 6.4 and for one of the queries I'm getting different results (query and explain are both from ES 6.4)

This is part of my query:

```
"multi_match": {
        "query": "nike xl",
        "type": "cross_fields",
        "fields": [
          "name^10",
          "variants.params^10",
          "*desc^5",
          "manufacturer",
          "categories"
        ],
        "operator": "and",
        "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
```

And here is an explanation how this `multi_match` is exploded:

```
"explanation" : {
"value" : 0.0,
"description" : "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
"details" : [
  {
    "value" : 0.0,
    "description" : "no match on required clause (((variants.code:*NIKE XL*)^15.0 (((+((shortdesc:nik)^5.0 | (name:nik)^10.0 | categories:nik | (variants.params:nik)^10.0 | (longdesc:nik)^5.0) +((shortdesc:xl)^5.0 | (name:xl)^10.0 | categories:xl | (variants.params:xl)^10.0 | (longdesc:xl)^5.0))~1) | manufacturer:nike xl) (name_na:*xl*)^10.0 #type:product)~1)",
```

Notice one thing. All fields from `fields` in the query search on the `nik` and then also on `xl`. But manufacturer does not, it looks for `nike xl` there. And I believe that's the reason why the document is not found. Does anyone know why is it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that it's the `operator` claues that causes the issue. I could not find anywhere in the documentation what `operator` means in context of `type=cross_fields`. Documentation says this:

`In other words, all terms must be present in at least one field for a document to match.`

taken from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields

Which to me translates that `operator` is not really needed here. When I removed it I started getting results as expected. Notice that in ES 2.4, this behaved differently (as if the `operator` was ignored)